# MongoDB search on keywords

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to create a search function to search through a collection stored in mongo. I would like to be able to search based on keywords.

Example: search users by typing "adam" return objects with keyword "adam" in one or more of the attributes.

But how can I search the entire object for the keyword instead of only one attribute?

I've got it working by searching all of the fields one at a time and appending the results together but that's kind of messy and I don't like it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would you return a document when the it contains a key as 'adam'?

Answer (score 0):

You can use mongodb text search feature by adding text indexes on collection fields. Please have a look at mongodb docs, which explains it with examples

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to index an array field.

```
> db.myColl.find().pretty()
{
     title: "My post"
     tags:  [ "Linux", "SO" ]
}

> db.myColl.ensureIndex({ tags: 1 })
> db.mycoll.find({ tags: "Linux" }).pretty()
{
     title: "My post"
     tags:  [ "Linux", "SO" ]
}
```